# How to send file contents in GET request

Tags: file, http

My robot has a web-based Lua IDE, and now I send the script contents with a GET request, Base64 Encoded. But for some reason, my server sometimes only decodes a part of the file, and sometimes it works just fine with a way longer file. I've written the server myself in C++ ([it's on GitHub](https://github.com/DirkWillem/LionFish)
), and it uses libmicrohttpd

Is there a more reliable way of sending files through a HTTP request than the method I'm using right now?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Do you expect us to fully read your server project now to understand what you are doing?

Comment: No, I'm asking if there is a better way of sending a file over HTTP than Base64 encoding it and putting it in a GET request, I'm sorry if it was unclear

Comment: I don’t understand how you can put a file in a GET *request*. A GET request has no body, so you can’t send non-header data (or do you have the file content base64-encoded in the URL?). And if you mean a response to a GET request, then you can just return the file directly in the message body—as binary, without having to encode it.

Comment: I put it in the URL as a parameter (eg. `http://192.168.2.8/saveFile?contents=base64encodedstring`), I know that that isn't a good idea, but I wouldn't know how to do it in a different way

Comment: Send a POST or a PUT request and include the content in the request body then.